# Failing to add WindowsAzure.ServiceBus in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Getting the following error while trying to add the WindowsAzure Service Bus package for push notification using NotificationHubs in Xamarin Android project.

```html
Adding WindowsAzure.ServiceBus...
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager'.
Adding 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 2.0.3' to PushNotification.
Could not install package 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 2.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.4', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the Servicebus libraries are compatible with Xamarin.
But you can use REST API to access Servicebus if you want.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780717.aspx

Comment: (Almost) one year later, is this still the case?